# How to Add custom shape button in fixed Location in QWidget

Tags: qt

I am new to Qt. First look at the image.

http://i225.photobucket.com/albums/dd200/saravanan_comp2001/sample.png

i already created custom shape button (inherit  the QWidget). now the problem is adding the buttons into another widget(Parent QWidget).

How to add this button in Fixed location and some times i need to add the buttons in overlap.

i can't use any Layout method. Please help me to fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

Just create your custom shape button with the QWidget as parent and set the position using the [`move`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qwidget.html#pos-prop) function.